# Histogram Correlation Specific Column

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, correlation

I have a csv file that has 36 columns, I wanted to keep one column constant and find the histogram correlation between it and the rest of the 35 columns remaining but I could not figure out how to choose that individual column

I have made a prototype csv file that consists of 4 columns and 4 rows.
http://www.filedropper.com/finalcombine

Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

import seaborn as sns

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv('D:\\Project\\database\\FinalCombine.csv')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(50,35))

sns.distplot(df.corr(),y='Power_KW',color='g')

sns.plt.show()
```

Comment: Provide data and any code you have created that attempts what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @merit_2 I uploaded my current code, the column I need to find the correlation with the rest of the column is called Power_KW but I'm not sure if that is the right way to do it.

Comment: In question-related to `pandas` and `data frames`, do not write the `read_csv`, it is practically impossible for others to visualize the data-frame. Try making the small test data-frame and print it in the question for better understanding.

Comment: @Rohit I'm really sorry, since I'm new too all of this I really don't understand what exactly you said, should I write a dummy code to give a better understanding of what is needed?

Comment: @AliYoussef, @Rohit's point is that if someone on Stack Overflow runs your code, it won't work because we don't have `FinalCombine.csv`.  Instead, post a small sample that explicitly creates a sample dataframe with, say, four rows.

Comment: @NicholasM Oh okay, I'll work on it now then, thank you very much.

Comment: Hello Ali, welcome on StackOverflow. [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) is a good place to start if you want to get high quality answers. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

According to the the documentation for [`corr`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html):

The returned df is a correlation matrix. You have to select specific rows & columns to visualize.

So, by updating your example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv('D:\\Project\\database\\FinalCombine.csv')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(50,35))
sns.distplot(df.corr()['A'],y='Power_KW',color='g')
sns.plt.show()
```

This will plot the correlation between column `A` and the rest of the columns, including itself.